# Resolving error with operands of type object and int

Tags: c#, object, grasshopper

I'm trying to process a list of decimals that are input into a C# Script block in Grasshopper. object x receives input list of decimals and ref object A should hen output the solution. Currently though I'm getting this error:

`1. Error (CS0019): Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int' (line 59)`

```
private void RunScript(object x, ref object A)
  {
    int intNum = new int();
    intNum = Convert.ToInt32(x);
    A = x - intNum;
  }
```

I'm not understanding why this isn't working, any insight would be amazingly helpful. Thank you!

Comment: As the error says, you can't use operator - on an object and an int. `x` is an object, `intNum` is an int, and you try to subtract them.

Comment: C# is a statically typed language. It means if you want to apply the subtract operation, you should have two number-typed variables, not an `object` and an `int`.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "process". Even if I mentally replace the `object` type with something list-like, I don't get how you can subtract something from a list.

Comment: I think what I need to do is iterated through the list object and perform my operation on each element

Comment: If `x` is a list of decimals then why are you converting it to an integer instead of a list of decimals? And why are you assigning zero to intNum right before assigning a different value to it?  And why are you writing `0` as `new int()` ?  None of this code makes any sense so it is hard to give you any good advice.

Answer (score 3):

If what you want to do is take a list of decimals and subtract one from each, mutating the list, you do this:

```
void MutateList(List<decimal> values)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < values.Count; i += 1)
    values[i] -= 1m;
}
```

If what you want to do is take a list of decimals and return a **different** list where the new list is the same as the old list, but every element one smaller, that's:

```
List<decimal> NewList(List<decimal> values)
{
  return values.Select(v => v - 1m).ToList();
}
```

If for some reason you are constrained by your scripting system to the signature:

```
void RunScript(object input, ref object output)
{
}
```

Then **you do exactly the same thing as before**.  If you need to mutate a list, you do this:

```
void MutateList(List<decimal> values)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < values.Count; i += 1)
    values[i] -= 1m;
}
void RunScript(object input, ref object output)
{
    MutateList((List<decimal>)input);
}
```

You **keep yourself in the world of sensible types as much as possible**.

Similarly, if you need to return a new list:

```
List<decimal> NewList(List<decimal> values)
{
  return values.Select(v => v - 1m).ToList();
}
void RunScript(object input, ref object output)
{
    output = NewList((List<decimal>)input);
}
```

Keep everything statically typed as much as possible, and write sensible, normal C# code.  **Only use a weird interface where you are required to use a weird interface**.  Everywhere else should be normal, statically typed C# code.

Comment: I'm assuming his function is some kind of Grasshopper thing, and so he's stuck with the objects. Though, obviously, I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You must cast to Int32 your variable x. You can't subtract from object

```
    private void RunScript(object x, ref object A)
    {
        int intNum = new int();
        intNum = Convert.ToInt32(x);
        A = (int) x - intNum;
    }
```

Comment: Unless `int` ends up a `Int64` you may as well just save some time and write `A = 0;` Although, none of that is actually what OP is after, apparently.